# I want my horizontal scroll bar enable all the time

Tags: html, css

I want my horizontal scroll bar enable all the time. Actually when I scroll horizontally it comes up and when I move my pointer anywhere else then it gets hidden all the time, so I don't want it to be disabled. Please help...

Comment: Hi there, please look at this guide [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: what device are you on?

Comment: I just need the property by which I can change it...

Comment: macbook and chrome browser and it's same with safari as well...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just override the css (customize it the way you want) and it will always be there:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 3px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #f1f1f1;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #dcdcdc; 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #555; 
}
```

Comment: It's working bro, thanks...

Comment: @MohitKumar You are welcome. Can you mark the answer as well. Thanks :)

Comment: done bro, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

use `overflow-x: visible` to your element